# How to decode an image on the GPU while training a network in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm training a model in Keras on a very big dataset that is too large fit directly into memory. In order to reduce its size and fit it into memory, I keep the binary PNG-encoded version of the dataset in memory and then decode the images with PIL batch by batch before feeding them into the network.

This method speeds up the computation, however, decoding a batch of PNG images requires longer than the training itself, and the GPUs are starving. To speed up the training even more, I was thinking of feeding the model with the binary PNG files and let the GPUs doing the decoding. I'm using Keras with Tensorflow as backend and I found a [function of Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_png) to decode PNGs. I'm trying to implement that function in a custom layer of Keras, and here is where I'm having problems.

I created a custom layer for Keras where the call method uses the Tensorflow function to decode PNGs:

```
from io import BytesIO

import keras
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Layer, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from tqdm import tqdm


class DecodePNG(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(DecodePNG, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(DecodePNG, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return K.tf.io.decode_png(x)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from keras.datasets import mnist

    batch_size = 100
    num_classes = 10

    # input image dimensions
    img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

    # the data, split between train and test sets
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

    # Simulate my dataset by encoding MNIST in png
    x_train_png = np.zeros((x_train.shape[0]), dtype=object)
    for i in tqdm(range(x_train.shape[0])):
        sbuf = BytesIO()
        image = Image.fromarray(x_train[i, ..., 0].astype('uint8'))
        image.save(sbuf, format='png')
        x_train_png[i, ] = sbuf.getvalue()


    inputs = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
    net = DecodePNG(output_dim=(28, 28))(inputs)
    net = Conv2D(4, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(net)
    net = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='valid')(net)
    net = Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, padding='valid')(net)
    net = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, padding='valid')(net)
    net =  Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding='valid')(net)
    net = Flatten()(net)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(net)


    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train_png, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=100,
          verbose=1)
```

The problem is that Tensorflow is expecting a single input rather than a batch of images, and it raises an error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'decode_png_1/DecodePng' (op: 'DecodePng') with input shapes: [?,1].

On the other hand, Keras is expecting to work with batches of images, not single elements. How can this be solved?

Comment: `decode_png` executes the actual decoding on the CPU using libpng. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4213d5c/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_image_op.cc#L236

Comment: Oh no, that's a shame... Isn't there a way to run the PNG decoder on the GPU? I know that nvidia has nvvl, which does exactly that for videos, but I couldn't find anything for PNGs...

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/DALI  and move to jpeg's?